# twilio + Azure File Stogare = The resource doesn't support specified Http Verb

Tags: azure-files

I am a new with twilio.

I am trying to make a call using CallResource.Create(to, from, url: _url);

regarding the URL : I have the Azure account. I have uploaded custom xml. 
Below you can find my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Say voice="alice">Thanks for trying our documentation.Enjoy!</Say>
<Play>http://demo.twilio.com/docs/classic.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

For testing i am using test message.
http://demo.twilio.com/docs/classic.mp3 , in the future i am planning to upload custom mp3 file also to azure file storage.

The end URL is 
https://xxxx.file.core.windows.net/xxxxx/20180719112627.xml?sv=2017-11-09&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2018-07-31T18:27:28Z&st=2018-07-01T10:27:28Z&spr=https,http&sig=gNqLuAofhePeOzuyVFWHSb0TCydgIW3ShOrRRfFEZ7o%3D

Unfortunately, i have got the exception:

"An attempt to retrieve content from https://xxxxxxx.file.core.windows.net/xxxxxxx/20180719112627.xml?sv=2016-05-31&sig=Pa4ery3QIruwYbNSJ1Nu7Y3EpKLjbd5mJXi46vnpoyU%3D&spr=https%2Chttp&se=2019-07-19T09%3A26%3A53Z&srt=sco&ss=bfqt&sp=raupwl returned the HTTP status code 405"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>UnsupportedHttpVerb</Code>
    <Message>The resource doesn't support specified Http Verb.
RequestId:907409a8-d01a-0051-1c43-1f4bf1000000
Time:2018-07-19T09:30:41.8204847Z</Message>
</Error>
```

Rerarding CORS for FILE SERVICE : [image: Image Example]
it is

Is there a document/guide describing the requirements how to configure the azure environment for integration with twilio?

Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the SAS url by generating one using Storage Explorer or Azure Portal?